# Does making a new local branch automatically make a new tracked remote branch?

Tags: git

If I'm working on a branch A and `git checkout master` and then make a new branch B with `git branch B`, will this new branch automatically make a tracked branch on the remote repo? Thus, whenever I push from this branch, it will push to a new remote branch 'B' on the remote repo.

Comment: no, it will create when you push your data `git push origin your_branch`

Comment: so doing this without the -u option will only create a remote branch that it pushes to once, correct? if I did include the -u option, the current branch will become a tracking branch that tracks the remote branch and automatically push to that branch without me having to designate it after typing 'git push'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tracking branch is ever created automatically; it is a result of a direct user instruction.

I should point out that there are differences between creating a remote branch and creating a remote branch which is tracked locally.  You can create a remote branch by pushing the branch you created right away, but that won't cause it to be tracked.  You create a *tracked* branch one of two ways:

- After the branch has been pushed and you are on the local branch you wish to track it with

  ```
  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branchname
  # or
  git branch -u origin/branchname
  ```
- Before the branch has been pushed and you are on the branch you'd like to push

  ```
  git push -u origin branchname
  ```

For more nuance into the above two commands, [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/1079354) provides a lot more detail.

Comment: just to be clear, the -u option makes your local branch track the newly create remote branch, so that you can conveniently push to it without having to designate the remote branch each time, correct?

Comment: Depending on your [push options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) (search for `push.default`), then that is absolutely correct.  You're likely using the default "simple" so you don't have anything to worry about in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The remote branch is created when you push, not when you create the local branch.